# Why is css rule taking precendence

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have 2 rules that i apply to an html element, `nav` and `pull-right`

**html**

```
<ul class="top-header__nav nav nav-inline pull-right">
                <li><a href="#">Acceussil</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Acsssceuil</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Accessuil</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Accesssuil</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Accesssuil</a></li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
.nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.pull-right {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

normally, `ul` should have `margin` right to `auto`, but the nav `margin:0` take precedence why??

-- here is an image of chrome developper tools :

[image]

Comment: In the above example, `pull-right` would override both the default margin as well as `nav`'s margin. What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: exactly, but its do not, top-header__nav have margin set to 0

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. If you're talking about `nav`'s margin, well, the `margin:0;` from nav only applies to `margin-right`, `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` whereas `margin-left` is overridden by `pull-right`'s property.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem check the image that i posted.

Comment: It's weird, I don't have the same behavior as you have in the same example : http://jsfiddle.net/KZdJK/111/
Here, margin-left: auto; is applied

Comment: @VincentG  css order matter, the last rule override other rules when applied to the same element

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it thanks to the @AndrewLyndem answer. The order in the inspector console was not the same as the order of the OP question, so is my misunderstanding :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the screenshot posted, the `pull-right` class is on **line 32** whereas the `nav` class is on **line 38** which explains why `nav` overrides `pull-right`.

It doesn't matter if you place the HTML codes like this:

```
<ul class="top-header__nav nav nav-inline pull-right">
```

Or like this:

```
<ul class="top-header__nav pull-right nav nav-inline">
```

as the succeeding property in your css overrides the preceding property in your css (unless **`!important`** tags are used of course).